# Google Maps GEOJSON GeometryCollection show only one geometry

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

In my GEOJSON data layer I have a set of about 20 regions. Each Feature has a GeometryCollection with two geometries: a Polygon to define the region, and a Point that gives the centre of the region.

I want the Polygons to be invisible, but show the Points on the map as markers.

Additionally, I want to be able to set the region markers as visible or invisible depending on zoom level.

Is it possible to show just the Points on the map, and set them visible / invisible separate to the Polygons? I know I can add them to the map as markers the normal way, e.g.

```
new google.maps.Marker(etc)
```

but ideally I want to use the stock data layer so I can turn the markers off and on without looping through an array.

Comment: Use markers. They are the way to add "points" to a map.

Comment: They are one way, but it seems data layers are more efficient and I'd like to investigate if the above is possible. If not, I'll go with markers.

Answer (score 0):

GEOJson is basically a "features collection", which means it can contain various features (and feature types: Point, MultiPoint, Polygon, etc.).

In your use case, you could have your Polygons and your points as separate features. You can then do various things with each feature separately. You can remove a feature, or you can override its style.

You can use `map.data.getFeatureById('your_feature_id');` then use one of [the available methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/data?#Data) of the Data layer, for example `remove` or `overrideStyle`.

As an example, please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/15tf4d03/) that demonstrates how you can add a few points (MultiPoint) and a Polygon to the Data layer, then hide/show only one feature.

Hope this helps.